# Out of stock validation in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am new to programming and selenium webdriver, i am trying to do the below in website, could you please help

Step1. select a random item from https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/smartwatches/#sort=content.sorting.featured&page=1

which when clicked will navigate to https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/smartwatches/samsung/gear-s2/#contractType=nonconnected

here i need to check whether the item is instock or out of stock

if its out of stock, i need to comeback to Step1

and select next item.

Can anyone pls help either with function in java?

Comment: Can you attach  URL of an item which is out of stock ?

Comment: finally got one :) https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/accessories/kitsound/mini-buddy-speaker/#contractType=nonconnected           and its navigated from this page https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/accessories/all/#category=headphonesandspeakers&sort=content.sorting.featured&page=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try with this.**

```
// Step1: Go to watch page.
driver.get("https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/smartwatches/#sort=content.sorting.featured&page=1");

// Step2: Click on selected watch
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mywatch"));
driver.click(element);

// Step3: Get the status of watch
String item_status = driver.findElement(By.className("status-info")).getText();

//Step4: Navigate back if selected item is 'Out of Stock'
if(status.equals("Out of Stock")){
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the condition like below :

```
// After product details page

List<WebElement> outOfStockItem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='delivery-information']/span[contains(.,'Out of stock')]"));

if(outOfStockItem.size()>0)
{
    driver.navigate().back();
}
else
{
        // perform your further actions here
}
```

**Explanation :** Once your page land on Product details page  e.g. https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/accessories/kitsound/mini-buddy-speaker/#contractType=nonconnected on this URL. It will check if there is any out of stock element present or not . If present then it will navigate the page to previous page . In else condition you can manage your code for further processing

OR you can write this code after select the product color because on given site, Some product  whose some color are out of stock.